# flash message not displaying after redirect or render

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using rails 4 and ruby 2

Having trouble displaying the flash messages from my controllers. My method looks like this:

```
def create
    @salary_report = SalaryReport.create(salary_report_params)
    if @salary_report.save  
      redirect_to @salary_report
      flash[:notice] = "Lönerapporten sparades korrekt!"
      puts "salary report saved #{flash[:notice]}"
    else
      render :new, notice: "Något gick fel när lönerapporten skulle sparas!"      
    end
  end
```

As you can see, I have added a puts statement printing out the flash notice just to prove that the flash notice is getting generated after the redirect.

The logs look like this after creating a salary report:

```
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/salary_reports/20
salary report saved Lönerapporten sparades korrekt!
Completed 302 Found in 25ms (ActiveRecord: 9.7ms)
```

After getting to show view logs:

```
Started GET "/salary_reports/22" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-07-24 16:08:42 +0200
Processing by SalaryReportController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"22"}
  SalaryReport Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "salary_reports".* FROM "salary_reports" WHERE         "salary_reports"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "22"]]
  Document Lo ad (0.3ms)  SELECT "documents".* FROM "documents" WHERE          "documents"."salary_report_id" = ?  [["salary_report_id", 22]]
  Rendered salary_report/show.html.erb within layouts/application (6.1ms)
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 3 ORDER BY     "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
Completed 200 OK in 62ms (Views: 58.0ms | ActiveRecord: 1.1ms)
```

In the view, I show the messages with this:

```
<% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
      <% if msg.is_a?(String) %>
        <div class="alert alert-<%= name == :notice ? "success" : "error" %>">
          <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&#215;</a>
          <%= content_tag :div, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}" %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

I have tried a variety of different ways to write the controller method but nothing seems to help. Very uncertain about what the problem could be.

Comment: just to clarify, the order where you placed the flash message doesn't matter as long as you don't explicitly call `return` before setting the flash message.  Are you sure you don't get redirected twice after creating the salary report?

Comment: only one redirect. See logs above.

Comment: yep i see that. but what happens when you get to the show action? that's not included in the question.

Comment: I have added the logs for after I get to show view.

Comment: sorry, i ran out of ideas. try to use debugger in the `show` action to see if the flash is getting passed there.

Comment: Did you solve the problem, Jasson?

Answer (score 5):

You are setting your `flash[:notice]` after redirect.  Try switching the order of those calls i.e. set the flash message first then redirect second:

```
def create
    @salary_report = SalaryReport.create(salary_report_params)
    if @salary_report.save  
      flash[:notice] = "Lönerapporten sparades korrekt!"
      puts "salary report saved #{flash[:notice]}"
      redirect_to @salary_report
    else
      render :new, notice: "Något gick fel när lönerapporten skulle sparas!"      
    end
  end
```

Comment: That gave the same result unfortunately

Comment: @JasonCarty, where do you have the `<% flash.each do |name, msg| %>...<% end %>` block placed?  Is it in the layout or is it in your  `show` view?

Comment: I tried it out in both the show view and application.html.erb

Comment: @JasonCarty, well in that case have you checked the source of the page (view source in the browser) and checked if those alert divs are getting generated.  Very unlikely but its possible that those divs are hidden via css, second possibility is there is a bug in Rails 4 with flash notices.

Comment: I have checked the source of the page and nothing. What does one do it is a Rails 4 bug?

Answer (score 0):

Try defining flash message in a redirect clause:

```
def create
  @salary_report = SalaryReport.create(salary_report_params)
  if @salary_report.save  
    redirect_to @salary_report, notice: "Lönerapporten sparades korrekt!"
  else
    render :new, notice: "Något gick fel när lönerapporten skulle sparas!"      
  end
end
```

Comment: that gave the same result unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

try use flash.keep.

Anything you place in the flash will be exposed to the very next action and then cleared out.

In this case flash pass into 2 actions, another controller and a view.

```
def create
  @salary_report = SalaryReport.create(salary_report_params)
  if @salary_report.save  
    flash.keep[:notice] = "Lönerapporten sparades korrekt!"
    puts "salary report saved #{flash[:notice]}"
    redirect_to @salary_report
  else
    render :new, notice: "Något gick fel när lönerapporten skulle sparas!"      
  end
end
```

Comment: Maybe it's because you use it in your puts method try  `flash.keep[:notice] = notice = "Lönerapporten sparades korrekt!"` then `puts "salary report saved #{notice}"`

Answer (score 0):

First off, instead of defining the flash message separately, put it inline with your redirect, just like you're doing with your render line below. This is more of a style change than anything majorly functional:

```
def create
  @salary_report = SalaryReport.create(salary_report_params)
  if @salary_report.save  
    redirect_to @salary_report, notice: "Lönerapporten sparades korrekt!"
  else
    render :new, notice: "Något gick fel när lönerapporten skulle sparas!"      
  end
end
```

As for the reason why it is not displaying, this is most likely an issue with your flash message view code. This is because, as you have tested, the flash hash is being set properly, it's just not being displayed.

Try temporarily replacing your flash message code with the following simpler version.
Ensure it's in your application.html.erb near the top, but that's again just styling:

```
<% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
  <%= content_tag :p, msg if msg.is_a?(String) %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got pretty the same problem due to devise gem and I found a solution with the cookies.

You have to set a cookie with a value before redirecting, and then the controller tests if there is a cookie. If yes, it tests what is its value and display the flash message.

Take a look right there for a complete explanation :
[flash[:notice] not working with the after_sign_out_path_for - (devise)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18979454/flashnotice-not-working-with-the-after-sign-out-path-for-devise)

Hope it can help you.