# Rails upgrade from 3 to 4 broke the flash messages on redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect

After an upgrade from rails 3 to rails 4 none of the flash messages works after a redirect.

Here are couple of examples of the redirects.

```
redirect_to(user_account_path(user, anchor: params[:tab]), notice: "Your account has been updated" })

redirect_to(root_path, notice: "Your account has been deactivated.")

redirect_to user_account_path(anchor: "networks"), notice: "Your primary network has been changed."
```

Any idea what could have caused the problem?

Here is the view/layout/app.html.haml

```
    - unless flash.empty?
      - flash.each do |name, msg|
        - next unless [:alert, :error, :notice].include?(name)
        %p.flash_message{id: name}
          = msg
```

By the way, flash without redirects works fine. So, I know the problem is not with the view.

Comment: try like this: **flash[:notice] = "Your account has been deactivated."**                                    
    **redirect_to root_path**

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've tried this and it still didn't work.

Comment: Try this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17835454/flash-message-not-displaying-after-redirect-or-render

Comment: For test proposes, what if you force it with `add_flash_types :notice` in your `ApplicationController`?

Comment: Those look fine, add to your question the section of your view/layout where you're displaying those.

Comment: @raj_on_rails That question doesn't seems to be resolved.

Comment: @RoquePinel I tried that and there was no effect.

Comment: @smathy I've just added the view/layout/app although I don't think that is the problem.

Comment: Your code looks fine. Have you checked if somebody changed redirect_to, for example in ApplicationController?

Comment: @SebastianvomMeer No, nobody changed that.

Comment: Ok, so that last line of information is a crucial piece that you should have led with :)  So, as a troubleshooting/testing step here, can you add a call to `flash.keep` above one of your redirects, and see if the flash shows up then.

Comment: @smathy Unfortunately, I've tried that too and it didn't work.

Comment: I see, very weird. FWIW, the way I upgrade Rails versions is to make two blank rails projects of each version, and do a `diff -r` of both of them to see any config or initialization differences. I'd recommend doing that if you haven't already, maybe there's some weird flash related thing you'll see.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm seeing the same thing. A new rails app works just fine, but my upgraded app has no flash messages post upgrade.  The flash code worked 100% with rails 3, but now flash is empty when it should be present in rails 4....  Can't for the life of me see what in the rails configuration would affect this...

Comment: @Paul I can't remember correctly what I did but I think it has to do with the `.css` and `.scss` extensions for the stylesheet

Comment: Thanks - I just figured out my issue too.  I'd added some ActionDispatch::Cookies stuff into application.rb to fix some Devise related issue during the upgrade, and that was the problem.  I can't remember _why_ that got added, but everything works fine without it...